# Updating to iOS 9.0 SDK framework project build failed

Tags: build, sdk, frameworks, ios9

I am new to iOS programming, recently I am working on a framework project. I am using iOS 8.4 SDK before, I use this project to generate framework for iOS device and simulator, then use some script to merge them into one framework.

My build settings: 
architecture: Standard architecture; i386
Valid architecture: armv7; arm64; i386

However, when I update iOS SDK to 9.0, there are some errors shown there. It used to build successfully in iOS 8.4.
It shows 
1./Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:707:2: Unsupported architecture
2./Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: Architecture not supported
3./Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:9: Unknown type name '__int64_t'
4./Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:9: Unknown type name '__int32_t'
.............and lots of similiar __int43/64_t
5./Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_intptr_t.h:30:9: Unknown type name '__darwin_intptr_t'
6./Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:11:10: Could not build module 'Darwin'

If I remove i386 from architectures, several errors will be gone. Also, if I change Apple LLVM 7.0 - Language - Modules: Enable Modules (C and Object-C) from yes to no, the module problem will be fixed. I can build the framework correctly.

However, when I use this framework in my framework test app, which used to work before as well. It will have some error: 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64.

Can someone explain to me what happened with the iOS update? How can I generate the correct framework I can use as SDK in another project.

Answer (score 0):

With iOS SDK 12.1, I received same error. The reason was when compiling with CMake I changed target architecture from x86_64 to arm64 but did not clean up build folder. After cleaning 
`/Users/yourname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and re-running CMake everything worked.